# Sonar Qube Error Update this implementation of 'ISerializable' to conform to the recommended serialization pattern

Tags: c#, odata, datacontract, .net-4.6.2, iserializable

I'm currently working on a .net 4.6.2 application.

I need to serialize an OData Api call and it works perfectly fine.

Unfortunately I'm getting a Sonar Qube Error:

**Update this implementation of 'ISerializable' to conform to the recommended serialization pattern.**

[image]

To get my OData into C#, I use the following class structure:

```
[Serializable]
public class Record : Dictionary<string, dynamic> { }

[DataContract]
public class Records
{
    [DataMember(Name = "@odata.context")]
    public string Context { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "@odata.count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public IEnumerable<Record> Value { get; set; }
}
```

The serialization works fine, but I don't know how to solve this Sonar Qube error.

How to properly use ISerializable together with DataContract, is it actually possible?

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: show the relevant code where you have `Serializable`

Comment: After I got the error, I put it on the Record class, but it's wrong

Comment: If you only use it for over-the-wire (de)serialization and don't consume it in code in such a way that requires binary (de)serialization support, you could just dismiss the error as irrelevant to your use case.

Comment: ok, I agree - unfortunately I may not dismiss this error, I need to find another solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a protected constructor with arguments as follows:

```
SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context
```

So the valid code is:

```
[Serializable]
public class Record : Dictionary<string, dynamic>
{
    protected Record(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {

    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Records
{
    [DataMember(Name = "@odata.context")]
    public string Context { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "@odata.count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public IEnumerable<Record> Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: and the key point is you need the attribute `Serializable` and the protected constructor

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Maritn Costello

you could suppress this warning like this.

```
#pragma warning disable S3925 // "ISerializable" should be implemented correctly
    public class Record : Dictionary<string, string> { }
#pragma warning restore S3925 // "ISerializable" should be implemented correctly
```

Dictionary class implement `ISerializable`

```
 public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable, IDictionary, ICollection, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback
    {
```

Comment: Thanks for that suppress message, it certainly is a possible solution.

Comment: Good to hear that

Answer (score 0):

In my case I chose to use the native type instead of a custom class.
It works fine.

```
[DataMember(Name = "value")]
public List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> Value { get; set; }
```